# Can I exclude words from a dictionary in PyEnchant?

Tags: python, pyenchant

Is it possible to exclude certain words from the dictionary when using PyEnchant? For example, I want to check if a word is english (`'en_EN'` in my case) or french (`'fr_FR'`). However, when I check on the string `"de`" against both dictionaries both return true.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to remove stop words before passing to Pyenchant

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

    def remove_stop_words(self, tokenized_docs_no_punctuation):
        """

        :param tokenized_docs_no_punctuation:
        :return:
        """
        # print 'CleanupText.remove_stop_words()'
        tokenized_docs_no_stopwords = []
        for token in tokenized_docs_no_punctuation:
            if not token in stopwords.words('english'):
                tokenized_docs_no_stopwords.append(token)

        return tokenized_docs_no_stopwords
```

Then those tokens pass them to Pyenchant